# backbone: relationship between models and views

Tags: backbone.js

in one of the Views (View A) of a backbone app I am looking at (which has multiple models), it has this line in its initializer

```
  this.model.bind('change', this.setText, this);
```

In another View (View B), it has this line in its initializer

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
```

However, nowhere in either View does it indicate which Model it is connected to. i.e. there's no declaration of what `'model'` is.  Does that mean that any Model that triggers a `'change'`, for example, will trigger `this.setText` in View A as well as (at the same time)  `this.render` in View B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

So when you instantiate a view with this:

```
var v = new SomeView({ model: m });
```

Backbone will automatically set `this.model` to `m` inside `v` and this will be done before `initialize` is called. Look for the constructor calls for the views that have those `bind` calls, you should see the `model` supplied when the views are instantiated.

> Does that mean that any Model that triggers a `'change'`, for example, will trigger `this.setText` in View A as well as (at the same time) `this.render` in View B?

No, each view (in this case) will have its own model that is supplied when the view is instantiated, the events will come from only that model.

Comment: thanks, I'm reading the documentation but when I'm wading through the code I forget what the heck I read....